# Fill an Array with different data types

Tags: java, arrays

i need to fill an Array with different data types

```
InvoiceItem[] invoiceItems;
int test = 3;
int i = 0;
```

This needs to be in the Array:

```
InvoiceItem invoiceItem = new InvoiceItem();
invoiceItem.setItemType("TestItem");
invoiceItem.setArticleNo("TestItemID");
invoiceItem.setDescription("TestDescription");
invoiceItem.setQty(1);
invoiceItem.setPrice(new BigDecimal(20.00));
invoiceItem.setVat(new BigDecimal(5.0));
```

There is the possibility that there is more than one InvoiceItem (test=3), so it needs to be in a loop.

It has to be an Array, i need to pass it to another class which only accepts an Arrays.

How can i achieve this?

**Edit:** I will try to make my question more clear:

I need to know how to put these

```
invoiceItem.setItemType("TestItem");
invoiceItem.setArticleNo("TestItemID");
invoiceItem.setDescription("TestDescription");
invoiceItem.setQty(1);
invoiceItem.setPrice(new BigDecimal(20.00));
invoiceItem.setVat(new BigDecimal(5.0));
```

in an Array:

```
int countofInvoiceItem = 3; // there are 3 InvoiceItem 

InvoiceItem[] invoiceItems = new InvoiceItem[countofInvoiceItem];
```

Where there can be more than one InvoiceItem.

Method looks like this:

```
public final ResponseCreateInvoice CreateInvoice
(Invoice Invoice, InvoiceItem[] InvoiceItems, Address DeliveryAddress, Address InvoiceAddress, String UserID, String Password)
```

(This is given and i can not change)

and returns

```
ResponseCreateInvoice inv = wsClient.createInvoice(invoice, invoiceItems, deliveryAddress, invoiceAddress, userID, password);
```

i am sort of new to Java (or arrays), so this may be an easy question, but i don't really get it. Also does it matter that there are Strings and Int, BigDecimal etc mixed together in an Array?

Comment: Where are the different data types?? there is only one type `InvoiceItem`, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Apart from `InvoiceItem` objects, what other type are you wishing to store?

Comment: We will all tell you: **don't do this** as it is a bad idea to mix types in an array for many many reasons. Mostly though, you'll never know what each item is. There is always a better solution, but you need to tell us the overall problem first. Note that this is a class XY Problem type question, one where the questioner is barking up the wrong tree and is concentrating on their wrong solution rather than on the question itself.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have an `InvoiceItem[]` array, and you need to fill that and then pass it to a method? What type of arrays does this other class accept? Can you post the method signature of the method you are trying to use?

Comment: So it doesn't matter if there are Strings, Integers etc mixed if it is all an object of InvoiceItem? I have a Method "CreateInvoice
 (Invoice Invoice, InvoiceItem[] InvoiceItems, Address DeliveryAddress, Address InvoiceAddress, String UserID, String Password)" where i need to pass InvoiceItems as an Array, but since im new to Java, i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit, your original question is off base. You do not want to create  an array of different types but instead only want to create an array of **one type** and one type only, that being an array of InvoiceItems. You are confusing object properties with array items, and they are not one and the same. This code here:

```
invoiceItem.setItemType("TestItem");
invoiceItem.setArticleNo("TestItemID");
invoiceItem.setDescription("TestDescription");
invoiceItem.setQty(1);
invoiceItem.setPrice(new BigDecimal(20.00));
invoiceItem.setVat(new BigDecimal(5.0));
```

is where you are changing the properties of a **single InvoiceItem**.

It seems that your InvoiceItem class has String fields for  item type, for article number, for description, an int field for quantity, a BigDecimal field for price and a BigDecimal field for VAT. And so your array would look simply like:

```
InvoiceItem[] invoiceItems = new InvoiceItem[ITEM_COUNT]; // where ITEM_COUNT is 3
```

You could use a for loop to then create your items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < invoiceItems.length; i++) {
   invoiceItems[i] = new InvoiceItem();
}
```

And you could perhaps use the same for loop to fill in the properties of each InvoiceItem in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < invoiceItems.length; i++) {
   invoiceItems[i] = new InvoiceItem();
   invoiceItems[i].setItemType(???);
   invoiceItems[i].setArticleNo(???);
   invoiceItems[i].setDescription(???);
   invoiceItems[i].setQty(???);
   invoiceItems[i].setPrice(???);
   invoiceItems[i].setVat(???);
}
```

But the unanswered question is, ... where do you get the data for each property of each InvoiceItem in the array? Is this information contained in a file? Is it inputted by the user? That is something you still need to tell us.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. This is what i need, i think. And yes, it seems i confused the properties and items. The InvoiceItems are Items in an existing Shop System. The User will choose them from the shop and set the quantity. Each InvoiceItem equals an Article in the Invoice. Articles will be passed from another class. Example would be: `invoiceItems.setPrice(anotherclass.price);` i will also get the `ITEM_COUNT` from this class. I hope this explains what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare your array as an array of type T where T is a superclass of all the classes of the objects you want to fill it with. In the worst case, it would be `Object` but it's bad design 9 times out of 10.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to **make a class** that holds everything you need as follows:

```
public class YourClass{

int id;
double value;
String description;
//and so on

//create getters and setters
}
```

And you can use this class to pass **array of objects** to another class.

```
Put your objects of the class in the Array
```

**For example**

```
YourClass[] objects = new YourClass[SIZE];//define number of objects you need
```

And you can pass each and every objects separately or as a whole to another class.

And in your receiving class, you can have a constructor as:

```
public YourRecievingClass(YourClass[] object){
//and recieve here as you need; ask further if you need help here too
}
```

I think this is the best way to adopt though your question is not 100% clear

Answer (score 0):

With which types of data? In general, you could use:

```
Object[] myArray;
```

All classes are subclasses of `Object`.